# 1-D barcode scanner(using images from a capturing device) implementation in java

Tags: java, algorithm, project, barcode

I am a student and as a project i have to implement a barcode(1-D) based attendance marking system.While surfing across the web i came to know that barcode readers are a bit costly toys to purchase,so now what I want to do is I want to capture images of barcodes through a capturing device(mostly a webcam) and then process them to get the content stored in it.

I found a few projects on the internet that do the same but they use .NET f/w and I am not so familiar with .NET technology. The only project that uses java is http://sourceforge.net/projects/javabarcoderead/ but somehow i am not able to run the jar file they are providing.

SO, I would like to know about the algorithms or methods that can be used for the same or even any project from where i can get some insight on how to move further with this...

Happy Coding...

Comment: What problems are you having with using the `javabarcoderead` library?

Comment: it is jar file containing MF file pointing to a main class,so I think it must be an executable one, and there is no documentation available for the same.
I also want to know the algorithms that can be used for the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, it would be very difficult to use a library with no documentation and no source code.

I'd suggest using [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/).  It's a well-documented library with lots of examples.